# AWS Glue Studio not saving Tables correctly

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

So, I am using AWS Glue Studio. After finishing the transformations I want, I want to save it to a table in the data catalog so that I can use it with Athena and I also want to save it in S3. Therefore I use the target node Amazon S3 and I click the button that says "Create a table in the Data Catalog and on subsequent runs, update the schema and add new partitions". This in fact creates a file in my S3 and also creates a table in the database.

However, once I open the table in Athena I realized that the schema I had created in AWS Glue Studio (which was col1 - Long, col2 - Long, col3 - string, col4 - string, col5 - null) has been replaced to where all of the columns are just strings. I then realize that the created table has all of the values in the first column and the rest of the columns are empty. Basically this happens,

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5

1| 2    | one  | two  | NULL
```

becomes

```
col1               | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5

1,2,one,two, NULL  |      |      |      |
```

Comment: Can you provide the Athena DDL and your script?

Comment: I was able to solve it by saving it as Parquet instead of CSV. However, it saves it all as strings instead of the data types I had on Glue Studio